# Character position

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string of characters in a cell which i want to extract some of it and paste it in a new cell.

For example i have these characters "11 23 77.6 556 7 696.5 33 22.1 34 23" in a single cell.

My goal is to separate all these numbers into a different cell.
For example: 11 will be in cells(1,1); 23 will be in cells(1,2); 77.6 will be in cells(1,3); 556 will be in cells(1,4); this goes on for the rest of the characters in the corresponding manner.

Therefore I wonder if there is any function that allows me to scan through each characters from left to right and detect if there is a space in between.

I come across MID function. But i wonder if there is a faster and more efficient way to do it

thank You

Comment: You can use the `Split` function with the space as the delimiter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function - That will turn the string into an array, which you can then process each element individually.

Comment: If your original data is also in cell(1,1) then you must either use Text-To-Columns or a VBA routine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub SplitString()
  Dim x As String, arr
  x = "11 23 77.6 556 7 696.5 33 22.1 34 23"
  arr = Split(x, " ")
  Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
End Sub
```

It will place each element in the range A1:J1. In fact, according do the array number of elements...

**Edited** to place a version returning doubles:

```
Sub SplitStringReturnDoubles()
  Dim x As String, arr, a() As Double, i As Long
  x = "11 23 77.6 556 7 696.5 33 22.1 34 23"
  arr = Split(x, " ")
  ReDim a(UBound(arr))
  For i = 0 To UBound(arr): a(i) = CDbl(arr(i)): Next i
  With Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1)
    .Value = a
    .NumberFormat = "#.00"
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @user13316884: Glad I could help! But, we here when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue, will know that this looked the most convenient. I am not talking about my code! Yo received 4 answers and I think it would be good the mark one of them in the terms I tried describe above...

Comment: The classical approach. - **Caveat:** the split returns strings, but no numbers. See my `FilterXML()` approach steering clear off this obstacle.

Comment: @T.M. Yes, it returns strings. But it will not be so complicated to make the code returning doubles, I think. I will adapt it to return in this way. i will also look to the `FilterXML` variant...

Answer (score 1):

Use the Split function

```
    Dim Texte As String
    Text = "11 23 77.6 556 7 696.5 33 22.1 34 23"
    Result = Split(Text)
    iResult = UBound(Result, 1)
    For i = 1 To iResult
        Cells(1, i) = Result(i)
    Next
```

Comment: Results can be written back easily by one code line, see @FaneDuru 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

**FilterXML() approach**

Splitting a string input returns an array of string elements; therefore writing these elements back doesn't result in *numbers* but **strings**.

Using the WorksheetFunction `FilterXML` (available since vers. 2013+) solves this problem and actually returns numeric array elements which can be easily written to a given range target. The above question requires a "flat" 1-dim array (in order to fill a row with results) and which will be created by default due to the 2nd function argument `IsFlat` *(whereas passing `False` would return a "vertical" 2-dim array)*

**Function**

```
Function GetItems(ByVal myItems As String, _
                  Optional IsFlat As Boolean = True, _
                  Optional Delim As String = " ")
'[1]get wellformed xml content out of myItems string
    Dim wellformed
    wellformed = "<items><i>" & Replace(myItems, Delim, "</i><i>") & "</i></items>"
'[3]return all xml node contents via FilterXML() function (where XPath search = "//i")
    GetItems = WorksheetFunction.FilterXML(wellformed, "//i")
    If IsFlat Then
        GetItems = Application.Transpose(GetItems)      ' change 2-dim array 2 "flat" 1-dim array
    End If
End Function
```

**Example call**

```
Dim s As String
s = "11 23 77.6 556 7 696.5 33 22.1 34 23"     ' or assign a cell value to variable s

'call function to assign an array with numbers
Dim arr As Variant
arr = GetItems(s)                              ' << call function GetItems()

'define any target and write the 10 resulting numbers e.g. in row 2:2
Sheet1.Range("B2").Resize(1, UBound(arr)).Value = arr
```

Comment: Voted up, for the fact it is able to directly return numbers. But I usually prefer the standard way and return whatever I need in a second array keeping converted elements...

Comment: It looks that the function returns an array with `LBound(arr) = 1`. So, the dropping should be done in a resized range using `UBound(arr) ` instead of `UBound(arr) + 1`...

Comment: Thanks for the hint: you are absolutely right, just oversaw this. Extending the upperboundary here would try to enter a non existant item to the row's most right cell thus displaying `#NV` (i.e. Error 2042). @FaneDuru

Answer (score 0):

1. In Excel you can use the `Text to Columns` option:
   Tab `Data --> Text to Columns`
   See the [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-a-cell-f1804d0c-e180-4ed0-a2ae-973a0b7c6a23).
2. In VBA you can use the `Split` function

From your example:

```
Dim strFull as String
Dim arrSplitStrings() As Variant
Dim i as Variant


strFull =  "11 23 77.6 556 7 696.5 33 22.1 34 23"

arrSplitStrings = Split(strFull, " ")

For i = LBound(arrSplitStrings) To UBound(arrSplitStrings)
   Debug.Print(arrSplitStrings(i))
Next i
```

3. Google Sheets has the Split built in as a function, so you can add the following to a cell:

`=Split("11 23 77.6 556 7 696.5 33 22.1 34 23", " ")`

See the related [docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)

4. You can use a combination of `LEFT`, `MID`, `RIGHT` and `SEARCH`

See this [link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/06/01/split-text-string-excel/) for an example

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are just wanting a simple **Text to Column** function. For this you can go to your Data ribbon under Data Tools and click on Text to Columns. Within the wizard for step 1 select "Delimited" and click "Next". Step 2 deselect "Tab" and select "Space" (this will assure that when the delimitation occurs it removes any unneeded spaces, unless there are multiple spaces between numbers). Click "Finish"

If you have multiple spaces between your numbers you can use a `=TRIM` formula. This will remove duplicate spaces leaving only one space between numbers/text. Example below:

A1 = `This    is   test  #   1.5`

Formula in B1 = `=TRIM(A1)`

B1 final = `This is test # 1.5`

Copy contents of cell (formula results) and past as "Values"

Execute Text to Column function to separate each number / text to is own cell; see image below.

[image]